# Negative powers of the determinant representation of $U(N)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, unitary-matrices, young-tableaux

Consider the determinant representation of $U(N)$ defined by $\det:U(N)\ni U\mapsto\det U\in U(1)$. If I'm not mistaken, $\det^{n}$ for $n\geq 1$ are all irreducible representations. When classifying irreducible representations with Young tableux, they correspond to tableux with $n$ columns, each of height $N$.

My question is: are negative powers of the determinant representation, $\det^n$ for $n\leq -1$, also irreducible representations? If not, how do they decompose into irreducible representations? Can we classify them using Young tableux?

Comment: They are one-dimensional, so obviously irreducible.

Comment: Yes. Pardon my stupidity. Are irreps of $U(N)$ really classified by Young tableux? It is true for $SU(N)$ but it seems that these determinant representations can't be.

Comment: Btw, the determinant representation does probably not correspond to a diagram with $n$ columns each of height $N$...

Comment: Represnetations of $U(n)$ are classified by pairs consisting of a Young diagram and an integer — the integer gives information about determinants, in fact.

Comment: See, for example, https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/twf_young.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: Look up "highest weight", and it's Young diagrams not Young tableaux which are relevant to this question.